# Error in code segment using find_if() with array

Tags: c++, stl

Here's my code snippet:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;


bool next(int j)
{
    return(j<3);
}

int main()
{
    ......
    cin>>m;
    int h[m];
    memset(h, 0, sizeof(h));
    .......

    int *p;
    p = find_if(h, h+m, next);
    ......
}
```

I'm getting the following error upon compilation:

> no matching function for call to ‘find_if(int*, int*, )’
>
> template _IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate)
>
> template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Predicate’

Comment: Present your [MCVE]. "......" tells us nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a victim of C++'s somewhat arcane lookup rules!

Because you didn't qualify `next`, and because you wrote `using namespace std`, and because `std::next` exists, [the compiler considers `std::next` a candidate (even though the lookup then fails) and nothing else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38690482/560648)!

Qualify your function:

```
find_if(h, h+m, ::next);
//              ^^
```

---

A testcase representing your code:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool next(int j)
{
    return (j<3);
}

int main()
{
    int h[5] = {};
    const size_t m = 2;
    find_if(h, h+m, next);
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6a73961ede32634))

And fixed:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool next(int j)
{
    return (j<3);
}

int main()
{
    int h[5] = {};
    const size_t m = 2;
    find_if(h, h+m, ::next);
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea2e6141cfb654b9))

Comment: @geedee see, this is a [MCVE]. That is expected of you to post in order to make our life easier when trying to help you. Please from now on do take the time to create a proper MCVE for your questions.